# Laravel 9 Won't count all users from database table error

Tags: laravel, database

Alright so, I've been trying to make it so on the main page (main.blade.php) theres a text saying that there's (this) many users registered. I did the code which is `{{ count(Schema::getColumnListing('users')); }}` but it's only counting 9 users even though I got 23 users registered.

Answer (score 2):

`getColumnListing()` returns the columns of the table. You should use `count()` on a `Laravel` model instead.

You already have a user model, from the base `Laravel` project. Using that, this will suffice.

```
{{ User::count(); }}
```

Comment: I got this error.. Class "User" not found

Comment: you have to include the user or use full path. \App\Models\User::count(); or what ever path the user model is located at.

Answer (score 1):

The `getColumnListing('users')` is not what you think it is. You might want to count rows here since you are talking about number of users.

Schema::getColumnListing('users') will return the columns of table i.e., `id, username, password` etc, do this instead:

```
User::count() // this will return the total number of rows
```